# Showing user ID on user main page from screen options

Tags: php, users, user-meta, screen-options

On the user main page in the screen options, you have some choices for displaying user information e.g.. e-mail, role, posts etc..

Is there a way to be able to display the user's unique ID?

Comment: Exactly where do you see this "user tracking" stuff?  Was this added by a plugin perhaps?

Comment: At the top of the screen you have 'Screen Options'  It allows you to show Role, e-mail, posts etc.. I want to add User ID to the list.  Not added by any plugin, default Wordpress functionality.

Comment: Ahh... you aren't talking about _tracking_ at all. Just showing or hiding those meta boxes.

Comment: I guess you are right.  I've updated my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use the filter [`'manage_' . $screen->id . '_columns'`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.5.1/wp-admin/includes/screen.php#L24) to add a column and [`manage_users_custom_column`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.5.1/wp-admin/includes/class-wp-users-list-table.php#L316) to display its value.

```
add_filter( 'manage_users_columns', 'column_register_wpse_101322' );
add_filter( 'manage_users_custom_column', 'column_display_wpse_101322', 10, 3 );

function column_register_wpse_101322( $columns ) 
{
    $columns['uid'] = 'ID';
    return $columns;
}

function column_display_wpse_101322( $empty, $column_name, $user_id ) 
{
    if ( 'uid' != $column_name )
        return $empty;

    return "<strong>$user_id</strong>";
}
```

With this, the ID will show up in the *Screen Options* as well.