# Code snippet to display ID gives critical error

Tags: errors

Based on [this post](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/101336), I added the code snippet below to my Wordpress site, as to display the ID in the Posts section of each post. However, it returns "critical error". Any idea what is wrong with this code?

```
add_filter( 'manage_posts_columns', 'column_register_wpse_101322' );
add_filter( 'manage_posts_custom_column', 'column_display_wpse_101322', 10, 3 );

function column_register_wpse_101322( $columns ) {
    $columns['uid'] = 'ID';
    return $columns;
}

function column_display_wpse_101322( $empty, $column_name, $post_id ) {
    if ('uid' != $column_name) {return $empty;}
    return "$post_id";
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately you can't just copy code that plays a completely different role and replace `users` with `posts` and somehow expect this to do what you want it. The reason you get a fatal error is because you're passing in too many arguments (3) to the filter, when there are only 2 supplied.

Here's the code to achieve what you need, if I understand you correctly:

```php
add_filter( 'manage_posts_columns', 'column_register_wpse_101322' );
add_action( 'manage_posts_custom_column', 'column_display_wpse_101322', 10, 2 );

function column_register_wpse_101322( $columns ) {
    $columns[ 'uid' ] = 'ID';
    return $columns;
}

function column_display_wpse_101322( $column_name, $post_id ) {
    if ( 'uid' === $column_name ) {
        echo $post_id;
    }
}
```